# How do I both randomly select rows from a data frame and delete each row as it has been selected?

Tags: r, random, dplyr

I'm randomly sampling without replacement from a data frame that consists of a single column. This column contains duplicated numeric values.

I'm using `dplyr` to do this. My data from which I need to sample looks like:

```
testSO <- data.frame(ToSample = c(round(runif(100, min=1, max=3),0)))
```

I use the code below to randomly sample 15 rows:

```
MyRandomSample <- testSO %>%
slice_sample(n=15, replace = FALSE)
```

Is there a direct method to remove each of these 15 samples from `testSO` as they are selected? Effectively, `slice_sample` is doing this under the hood. I can't locate a method for creating a list of the row indices to be able to remove these from `testSO`. Then I would simply delete the rows that match the row indices.

The real `testSO` data has some ordering effects, hence why I am using `slice_sample` instead of `slice_head`.

I can reorder `testSO` randomly and then `slice_head`. But is there a method for both drawing a sample and simultaneously deleting the sampled rows? I found a base R method using `-sample` that deletes rows from the data frame, but it doesn't then pass the deleted rows to another object.

Comment: There are a few ways you can retrieve and then delete these sampled frames: (1) if each row has a unique identifier (or combo of columns that *guarantee* unique matches), then you can `anti_join` the original frame with the random sample frame on that id; (2) you cannot use `slice_sample`, but you can `mutate(use = row_number() %in% sample(n(), size=15))` and the retrieve with `filter(use)` and then remove with `filter(!use)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can randomly draw row indices, and the use them for selection of the random samples as well as removing them from the original data.

```
rand_ind <- sample(nrow(testSO), 15, replace = FALSE) 
MyRandomSample <- testSO[rand_ind, ]
testSO <- testSO[-rand_ind, ]
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured there had to be a way to do it. Base R to the rescue!